# Reviews of pfSense

Tags: pfsense

Does anyone know of any professionally made reviews of pfSense (cnet, zdnet, etc...)?

I need to find one for a project of mine...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know if this is "professional" enough for you, but PFSense is a favourite firewall/edge device for a lot of people on this website. [Check out the list of questions here](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/pfsense).

Some good places to start might be:

- [Good, inexpensive 1U pfSense Server Config for 100 Mbps throughput, some IPSec, few VPN](https://serverfault.com/questions/213076/good-inexpensive-1u-pfsense-server-config-for-100-mbps-throughput-some-ipsec-f)
- [Barebones network appliance, 4+ GbE NICs, Intel chipset](https://serverfault.com/questions/134690/barebones-network-appliance-4-gbe-nics-intel-chipset)
- [monowall vs pfsense](https://serverfault.com/questions/63110/monowall-vs-pfsense)

Comment: For what it's worth, I'd trust many of the answers on this site long before I'd trust a cnet/zdnet "professional" review.

Answer (score 0):

Google reveals these "professional" reviews:

Techrepublic:
http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/linux-and-open-source/diy-pfsense-firewall-system-beats-others-for-features-reliability-and-security/

Techradar:
http://www.techradar.com/news/software/applications/7-of-the-best-linux-firewalls-697177